# How to make random points with bounds?

Tags: matlab, random, bounds

I want to make 100 random 3-dimensional points between lower bound [lx, ly, lz] and upper bound [ux, uy, uz].

I am using the code as follows

```
noPoints = 100;
LB = [lx, ly, lz];
UB = [ux, uy, uz];
repmat(UB-LB,noPoints,1).*rand(noPoints,3) + repmat(LB,noPoints,1);
```

However, I have just known that the following code

```
repmat(UB-LB,noPoints,1).*rand(noPoints,3) + LB;
```

gives the same result.
It makes me realize that "adding a row vector into a matrix is the same as adding the row vector into each row vectors of the matrix."
For here, I have a new curiosity.
Is there any method to remove function "repmat" totally?
Actually,

```
(UB-LB).*rand(noPoints,3) + LB;
```

is not working because the dimensions of two operands are incorrectly set.

Is there a fast, clean and simple code to make multiple random points under the boundary constraints??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution:

```
(UB-LB).*rand(noPoints,3) + LB;
```

works in R2016b and later versions of MATLAB, thanks to implicit expansion.

In Previous versions you can use [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) :

```
bsxfun(@times, UB-LB, bsxfun(@plus,rand(noPoints,3) , LB))
```

As of MATLAB R2017b you can use [`rescale`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rescale.html) :

```
rescale(rand(noPoints,3), LB, UB, 'InputMin', 0, 'InputMax', 1)
```

Comment: Oh my god, is it working??? Super nice MATLAB (although bad for many "for" statements)

Comment: Recently MATLAB jit compiler has been optimized and for loops are fast.

Comment: Nonetheless, the code in visual-C environment is much faster than in Matlab environment although the codes are the same. Thus, I initially make everything in Matlab due to easy implementation and good plotting function, and then re-make the same thing in C. Even though I am using the newest version of Matlab, C is much faster.... (maybe due to my newbie-like code.)